# ViewModel for Multiple Tables resulting in Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query multiple tables using a single view model. Here is my ViewModel

```
class sDTO
{
    public long c_id { get; set; }
    public string Exp { get; set; }
    public int B_Code { get; set; }

    public int C_No { get; set; }
    public int PickUp { get; set; }
    public string C_Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int C_Code { get; set; }
    public int L_Code { get; set; }
    public int S_code { get; set; }
}
```

I have a query that Lists all tables to Pick from and loops through the tables

```
var cQuery = string.Format(@"select top 1 a.c_id, a.Exp, a.B_Code, a.C_No, a.PickUp, c.C_Name , b.C_Code, b.L_Code, b.S_code,
                             c.Email from cards{0} a inner join hloding c on c.c_id = a.C_id 
                             inner join cAcs{0} b on b._id = a._id
                                    ", items); 
                using (eServiceContext _db2 = new eServiceContext())
                {
                    var res = _db2.ExecuteQuery<sDTO>(cQuery).AsEnumerable();
```

I discovered that  C_No in some tables are int and some are bigint. Hence the Error Specified Cast is not valid. These tables are already running on production. And i need to override in code. How do i do that

Comment: Only thinking there is a way to handle it in code

Comment: when i make it long and int is returned, i have the same error

Comment: Then you'll have to adjust your model. Perhaps create subclasses with their own implementation of `C_no` if you can't unify the type across all tables. I'm surprised you can't put a DB `int` in a `long` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error will be resolved if the type of columns would be the same, instead of changing the column type you can cast smaller type to the bigger type, so don't change the type of `C_No` in `sDTO` class and change your query to this

```
select top 1 ... , cast (a.C_No as bigint) as C_No, ...
```

Comment: Thanks. How did i not think about this